# 14.04 laptop - two finger scrolling not working but three finger does

Tags: laptop, touchpad, configuration

Is there a conf file for Ubuntu's touchpad driver I can play around with?

This is really strange. It's an Alps Glidepoint touchpad in a Dell Latitude 3340. Oddly enough when I install Dell's driver then the two finger works, but the mouse gets a lot input lag and has low sensitivity which I don't know if I can change.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. Check out `synclient`. The basic command gives You list of current parameter settings.